# Is there a way to add a hyperlink in a Word 2007 document to anchored text on a web page?

Tags: microsoft-word

I keep trying to add a hyperlink (eg www.website.com/#anchor) in my Word document  but when I click the link, the "#anchor" seems to get stripped off and I only get to the web page, not the location.  Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this and it works fine for me.

If you use the 'Insert Hyperlink' dialog (visible in the 'Insert' section of the Word ribbon) and enter the plain web page reference (e.g. http://www.website.com/) and click 'Bookmark...' Word will retrieve the page and list out for you each of the available anchors on that page. If there are no available anchors it will return 'There are no bookmarks in this document.'